# Why Can't I Batch Open a Website with %'s?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, escaping, special-characters

I am attempting to create a BatchOS for me and my friend that will show how many subs we have, but since our channel names have spaces, the website replaces those with "%20" s. Anyway I can get around this. Batch will open it up as https://livecounts.net/channel/Eternal0Dusk0Gaming, but I have typed https://livecounts.net/channel/Eternal%20Dusk%20Gaming. Can anyone help me?

```
start chrome https://livecounts.net/channel/Eternal%20Dusk%20Gaming
```

I havent run into this problem before. I use Notepad++ if that helps anyone. Doubt it will tho :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%0` to `%9` in batch are the parameters you passed to the batch file. As you have no parameter in the second position, it's replaced by an empty string

You need to escape `%` by `%%`

```
start chrome https://livecounts.net/channel/Eternal%%20Dusk%%20Gaming
```

Comment: Thank you it works! I appreciate it. And the duplicate questions, I apologize for it, I am fairly new to stack overflow, and searching for my probs in general. Thank you though!